# Google Maps with Bootstrap is not displaying in fulldomain

Tags: google-maps, bootstrap-4

My map shows in my [ISP provider URL](http://vps616.urltemporal.com/#location) and it doesn't on the [full domain](http://www.falconer.com.ar/#location).

I am using this script for displaying a multimaker google map:

```
    var locations = [['<b>Base de Operaciones</b><br>Ruta 9 km450<br>Marcos Jurez, Cordoba<br>Tel: 701-555-1234<br>', -32.6836311,-62.1571096, 4], ['<b>Oficina Comercial</b><br>Champagnat 466<br>Marcos Juarez, Cordoba<br>Tel:  (+54) 3472-425-532 interno 32<br>', -32.6944151,-62.1001607, 5]];
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      /* Zoom level of your map */
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.6935284,-62.1391514),
      /* coordinates for the center of your map */
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<section id="location" class="map">
    <h2><center>Ubicaci&#243n</center></h2>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="embed-responsive-item" >
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src='https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: There is an error in the javascript console: `Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error`  The key is now required, older domains that previously had maps before the key was required are grandfathered to keyless access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the js console to get to know what the problem is. Use your browsers inspector and navigate to the console. In your case it gives the following error:

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

It seems that the script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter.

Good luck! Hope this helps you!!

Comment: I checked that, and on both happens the same, if thats the error wouldnt it apply on both URLs?

Comment: Nicky you are right. My bad. I still dont get why it is asking on one URL for it and the other doesnt. How should the map refactor should work, I am bit of a newbie on google maps api, and how to change it on my html.

Comment: Did you get a key/token from Google to use in your code? Maybe you configured this token for vps616.urltemporal.com domain? Try getting a new one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: No, I never used a token for any domain, thats why it was a surprise for me. I used this map code from here https://codepen.io/engza/pen/Btedl, which didnt use any token.

Comment: Fixed, apparently the ISP had its own api key, and thats why it worked, I needed to recreate one for my domain and I added the api key to my HTML link like this      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURGOOGLEKEY"></script>